# How to find out operating system drive using java?

Tags: java, operating-system

How can we code in java to find out the drive letter on which operating system is installed ?

Comment: Are you aware that there are operating systems that do not follow the "Windows Drive Letter Concept"? Is this supposed to work on Windows only?

Comment: Yes, i am looking it for windows only.

Comment: @reto not really a duplicate because it uses the win32 api. Can't be called as is from java, you would need a JNI call.

Comment: @assylias you do have a point there, the most voted answer is however referring to the same system env. variable

Comment: Once upon a time the operating system used to be on the A: drive but that was long before windows.  Do you ever see users installing on a drive other than C: ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get that from the Environment:

```
System.getenv("SystemDrive");
```

Comment: it is not work for me, it is not standard environment variable in Linux;