# Reading a CSV file using an absolute path in java giving exception

Tags: java, csv, debugging, bufferedreader

I was trying to create a program to read a `CSV` file from the downloads folder on any windows computer and could not get the `Java BufferedReader` to find the file.

I read that java can handle absolute paths so I did:

```
File f = new File("%systemdrive%\\users\\%username%\\Downloads\\quotes.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

This threw an IOException with the message :

```
 %systemdrive%\users\%username%\Downloads\quotes.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I made sure that this file existed by entering the same path into `File Explorer` and easily enough, the file showed up.

I was wondering if something like this is possible and if there is some way to find and read this file.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

The `%systemdrive%` and `%username%` appear to be environment variables expanded by the File Explorer.

You might find this other entry in SO ( [How to find out operating system drive using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985034/how-to-find-out-operating-system-drive-using-java) ) interesting to get the value for `%systemdrive`. Similarly, you can apply the same call to `System.getenv` to get the username.

FWIW, [here](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/) there's a list of environment variables in Windows. Note the `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable, which points to the home directory of the current user.

With all these premises, you might consider the following code to fix your issue:

```
String userhome = System.getenv ("HOMEPATH");
File f = new File(userhome + "\\Downloads\\quotes.csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
String path = userHome + "\\Downloads\\quotes.csv";
File f = new File(path);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Comment: Even better use a system-independent path separator variable:        `String pathSeparator = File.separator;                                                String path = userHome + pathSeparator + "Downloads" + pathSeparator + "quotes.csv";`